# GTKMM Monitoring I/O example 100% CPU load

Tags: named-pipes, gtkmm, mkfifo

I am trying the Gtkmm Monitoring I/O example from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-monitoring-io.html.en).
After something has been written to the fifo, the CPU load goes to 100%.

The code as shown in the example link is the code I used for testing (copy / paste), I only removed the build.config.h header to compile it.

I compiled it using:

```
g++ -Wall -o test main.cc `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 sigc++-2.0 --cflags --libs`
```

After converting the code to Gtkmm 2 the behaviour is the same, CPU load still goes to 100% after something has been written to the fifo.

My question is, is this a bug or a known issue or maybe a non-issue?

Answer (score 1):

So I finally figured out how to get the CPU usage down, I changed the following line in the example:

```
read_fd = open("testfifo", O_RDONLY);
```

to:

```
read_fd = open("testfifo", O_RDWR);
```

Hope this helps someone.

The answer in [this thread](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtkmm-list/2015-September/msg00034.html) on the gtkmm mailing list describes what is going on.